# Constructing an open non Jordan measurable set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-writing

I am trying to construct an example of a bounded, open, non Jordan measurable set.

I enumerate the rationals in $(0,1)^2$ by $\{q_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ and define
$$B_n=\Big(q_n^{(1)}-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}, q_n^{(1)}+ \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \Big) \times \Big(q_n^{(2)}-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}, q_n^{(2)}+ \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \Big)\cap (0,1)^2,$$

where $q_n=\big( q_n^{(1)},q_n^{(2)} \big)$. I then define $B=\cup_{n=1}^\infty B_n$, and try to show that $B$ is not Jordan measurable.

I denote by $J^*$ the Jordan outer measure and by $J_*$ the Jordan inner measure, and am trying to show that $J^*(B)>J_*(B)$.

I think I've shown that $J^*(B)=1$ since $\overline{B}=[0,1]^2$, but I'm having problems showing that $J_*(B)\leq \frac{1}{3}$.

If I define $B_N= \cup_{n=1}^N B_n$, I can show that $J^*(B_N) \leq \frac{1}{3} \cdot \big( 1-\frac{1}{4^N} \big)$, but since I only have finite additivity and not $\sigma$-additivity, I am struggling to show that $J_*(B)\leq \frac{1}{3}$.

At some point I thought to myself that this was enough, but I ca't figure out how to show that any elementary subset $L\subset B$, a finite union of rectangles, $m(L)\leq \frac{1}{3}$. I think that this should be a relatively simple argument that I'm not seeing, and would appreciate any useful suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An elementary set $L$ is a finite union of non-overlapping closed rectangles.

If $L \subset B$, then $\{B_n\}$ is an open cover of $L$ and, since $L$ is compact, there is a finite subcover such that

$$L \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^m B_n$$

With $|L|$ denoting the area of $L$, it follows that

$$|L| \leqslant \sum_{n=1}^m |B_n| = \frac{\frac{1}{4} - \left(\frac{1}{4} \right)^{m+1}}{1 - \frac{1}{4}} \leqslant \frac{1}{3}$$

Thus $J_*(B)= \underset{L \subset B}\sup|L|   \leqslant \frac{1}{3}$.